Elevation for far away objects
I am trying to use a PTZ (pan, tilt, zoom) camera to point at far away objects that I have an exact bearing and distance of.
My main problem is getting the correct 'tilt' or elevation angle to point at. For close by objects I can get this right, but for far away objects the calculated pan is a fair bit too high. I believe this may be due to atmospheric refraction as below?

I want to be able to compensate for this but the only information on this I can find online is to do with compensating for atmospheric refraction of objects OUTSIDE of our atmosphere, but mine are at sea level and WITHIN our atmosphere.
It could be caused by something else though, this is just my suspicion?
The equation I'm currently using to work out the elevation angle is as follows (this takes into account the earth's curvature, rather than using simple trigonometry for a flat plane):

top = (distance**2) + (height**2) + 2*height*self.earthradius
bottom = 2 * distance * (self.earthradius + height)
theta_rad = np.arccos(top/bottom)

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong or how I could account for atmospheric refraction? My error for the elevation of the horizon is about 1 degree.
Cheers

It would help if you defined the variables in your program. What are top, bottom and theta_rad? Include a diagram so we can see what the math represents. My first thought is that it's weird that you are applying arccos to a ratio of squared distances.

Thanks for the comment, I've added a diagram. The equation is just the cosine rule though

have you tried using "simple" trig formula and got a worst error? also, just curious here, what is a scenario for an object inside atmosphere so far and big for earth's curvature to matter?

Is the camera located at the angle $\theta$?

Hey, yep I tried a 'simple' trig formular for a flat plane but this was actually worse and pointed the camera even higher. This is for spotting ships over the sea which are near to the horizon (up to ~5nm). You're right though the earths curvature doesn't make much difference but it did make a little.

The fact that your camera points too high leads me to believe that average atmospheric refraction is not the cause. As seen in your diagram, refraction tends to make objects appear higher than they actually are. Look at start C. If you pointed your camera at the actual position of C, the camera would not see the star. The camera must point at the apparent position C' which is at a higher elevation.
However, refraction could be a factor due to local temperature variations. Mirages are a classic example of temperature variations causing objects to appear where they aren't. Unfortunately, their affects are determined by local conditions in a way that can't be calculated ahead of time. In fact, the effect could be in either direction: mirage-like conditions require a lower elevation, while fata-morgana-type conditions require a higher elevation.
Ultimately, this might require daily or even hourly calibration. Point the camera at an object of known position, manually center the object, add the offset to your control software.
